# Linux and the Mysterious Case of Vanishing (and Reappearing) Directories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, root

I've set up my very first Ubuntu server and immediately logged in (as `myuser`) to begin customizing it. I go to `/opt` and run `mkdir sandbox`.

> mkdir: Cannot create directory 'sandbox' : Permission denied

Permission denied?!? Okay. So I run `sudo -i` and enter `myuser`'s password. Re-run the `mkdir` command, and voila! The directory is created. I log out.

I log back in as `myuser` and navigate to `/opt` and run `ls`: nothing! No visible directories inside `/opt`! What!?!?

So I sudo again with `sudo -i` and re-run `ls`. **Now** it sees `sandbox/`.

I think I'm missing some fundamental Linux knowledge with respect to users and roots. During the server configuration/installation, it asked me to create a user, which I did (`myuser`). I *assumed* this would also be the root user (with full admin privs) since it was not only the user I created during installation, its the very first user in the system!

So why is it that `myuser` can't:

- Create directories outside of `/home/myuser` without sudo-ing?
- See directories created when in "sudo mode"

I'm also vague on the difference between `sudo`, `su` and the `root` user.

Ultimately, in addition to fully understanding these basics, I'd like to have a bunch of server software installed under `/opt/sandbox/` that can be running around the clock and interacting with the local filesystem. Now I'm not sure if I should be installing these applications while logged in simply as `myuser`, sudoed as `myuser`, or something else.

These servers are inside a secured, private home LAN so I don't need "real admin" and crazy security controls. I'm just setting up a simple dev enviroment for a small software tool I'm writing. Thanks in advance for any help with the questions above.

Comment: Which shell did you use? Was it one of those who need a manual command to rehash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/opt by default is owned by user `root` and group `root`.

Try `l /` and you will see that the folder /opt is owned by "`root root`" which are the user and group respectively.

If you really want to create and modify files inside of /opt with a non-root user, you will need to create a folder in there and modify it's permissions so that it can be freely accessed by a non-root user.

Example:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/sandbox
sudo chown myuser:users /opt/sandbox
```

The first command creates the folder, but it is owned by `root` and group `root`
The second command changes the ownership (`chown`) to your user named `myuser` and makes it part of the group `users` (which `myuser` is a part of).

Comment: Thanks @SaultDon (+1) - just out of curiosity, how do software applications (installed either under `/opt` or `/usr/local`) access areas of the file system that are not under `/home/myuser` or owned by `myuser`? Are they creating their own users/groups under the hood and utilizing this `sudo chown` command that you give an example of? Or is something else going on? Thanks again!

Comment: There is definitely something else going on, but I am limited in knowledge in that area. A lot of programs access the files needed to run in "read" mode. Certain programs can require a separate user to function properly, like database programs. But in those cases, they are considered a "service" and services (like a database) usually require a separate user or group to function properly. A user (swerdna) from the openSUSE community has my fav page for learning about permissions (http://www.swerdna.net.au/sambaserver/modes.html) and what those crazy "drwxr...." options mean!

Comment: @zharvey cont'd: Usually, when the program is installed the needed user/group permissions are created. They usually don't change permissions when the program is launched or running, this is probably because of security reasons.

Comment: @zharvey You can see this in action, how you can read a file owned by root, but not another! Try `ls /bin` and that will work because your user has "read" access to that folder. But try `ls /root` and you may be surprised that only the root user has read access to that folder (if it exists).

Answer (score 1):

> **So why is it that myuser can't: ...**

Try

```
ls -l sandbox
getfacl sandbox
```

If the output of those isn't clear or doesn't explain what you are seeing, cut & paste output into an edit of your question.

> **I'm also vague on the difference between sudo, su and the root user.**

`sudo` gives you elevated root (i.e. administrator) privileges for one command only. There is a config file for sudo in which you can control which users are allowed to do what.

`su` gives you elevated priviliges for multiple commands by giving you a new shell session with an effective user-id of root.

The root user is a special user named root that you can see in /etc/passwd. There are a dozen or so other users you always get in an Unix or Linux system. People usually have an ordinary account and use that for all work except the actions that absolutely require root privileges (e.g. installing software for use by all users on the system). This makes it harder for malware to do bad stuff and makes it harder for you to make irrecoverable mistakes.

> **I'd like to have a bunch of server software installed**

I find it best to use the system's package manager to install packages. I would prefer not to create folders in /opt by hand, that would be my very last choice.

Comment: Thanks @RedGrittyBrick (+1) - great answer! When I run `ls -l sandbox` I get: `ls: cannot access sandbox: no such file or directory.` And `getfacl` isn't even installed on my system (I'd have to run `apt-get install`, but I seem to be having some network issues as well (outside the scope of this question), so for now it's not something I can run. I now understand the diff between sudo, su and root (so thankyou!) and like your idea about letting package managers do all the hard work for me...

Comment: ...but there are some apps and things I'd like to be able to install under `/opt` so that they are visible outside of `myuser`. In those cases, I assume I have to either be root or sudoed from `myuser` to have root-like privs. But that still doesn't make them "visible" to `myuser`! Can you explain why this is so, and what I need to be able to do to make them visible/accessible? Thanks again!